# how to convert parsed xml to doc?

Tags: xml, ms-word, doc

I have an xml file with CSS. I can see it parsed in browser, and I need to convert the parsed data to doc file. I mean, I'd like to make a doc file with color, font style, font size, etc. are adapted in it from an xml file with CSS. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use a fairly useful "cheat": generate HTML and give the resulting file a .doc extension. Word will silently open it as if it was a regular doc file. Double check to make sure Word properly renders whatever styling your documents have.

Comment: Thanks! And then, how can I generate HTML file from xml with CSS? Is there a available software?

Comment: @user1610952 Sorry, I'm really not an xml and CSS expert (or novice even). But if it renders in IE, and you can jam it all into one file (can you embed CSS in XML?), then try changing the file extension to .doc and see what happens.